# Run query on entire table in a specific MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database for storing log files.

Every 30 days the system creates a new table with a name that ends with date. For example it could be `log_01-11-2015`, `log_01-12-2015`, etc., and store the log month-wise.

My requirement is to search for their activity log within a date-range like starting from month January to December. Writing a long SQL union query is not applicable in the web application. I am using `php`; is there any way to do query within the databsse without writing a long union query by putting all the table names?
`TABLE_NAME : log_01-11-2015`
`Table_content`
`log_id`
`log-date_time`
`user_ip`
`activity_id`

`TABLE_NAME : log_01-12-2015`
`Table_content`
`log_id`
`log-date_time`
`user_ip`
`activity_id`  And so on. every first of the month system creates a new table and store data month-wise

Comment: I think you might have to use a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: I think you should review the database structure: it doesn't make sense to create so many tables.

Comment: You should consider using merge table or table partitioning to benefit from having multiple files for the same dataset, yet query them as a single table. The advantage of merge table is that every month you can add the newly created log table to the merged collection eith a simple alter table command. After that run the queries against the merged table.

Comment: @Aerendir post edited, Please refer the DB structure

Comment: I did this 
`SELECT * FROM log_01-12-2015,log_01-12-2015` getting Error Code: 1052
`Column 'log_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PHP, you could perhaps create your own UNION'ed query with PHP somewhat similar to this:

Test.php

```
<?php
$startdate = new DateTime('2015-01-01');
$enddate = new DateTime('2015-05-31');
echo getLogSQL($startdate, $enddate);

function getLogSQL($startdate, $enddate) {
    $select = 'select * from log_';
    $sql = $select . $startdate->format('Y-m');
    if ($startdate->format('Y-m') === $enddate->format('Y-m')) {
        return $sql;
    }

    while ($startdate <= $enddate) {
        $startdate = new DateTime($startdate->add(new DateInterval('P32D'))->format('Y-m-01'));
        $sql .= "\nunion all {$select}" . $startdate->format('Y-m');
        if ($startdate->format('Y-m') === $enddate->format('Y-m')) {
            return $sql;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Result:

$ /c/php/php.exe test.php

```
select * from log_2015-01
union all select * from log_2015-02
union all select * from log_2015-03
union all select * from log_2015-04
union all select * from log_2015-05
```

You can use and tweak the function to your needs with the kind of date/time format you use.

You can even add value to this function should you desire to not just get all data from the log files but also data between certain start and end dates falling within the month.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions, understood.
What to do  if the tables name ends  instead of  `log_2015-01` with a number series like `log_100` ,`log_101`,`log_103`

Comment: If your table names do not have an indication of date, it will be very tricky to do query on the right table(s). One option would be for you to store the start and end times of each log in a metadata table. Read that metadata table and then look for the right tables to query. As Aerendir and Shadow suggested, putting logs in a single table with MySQL partitioning might help. Archive logs older than a certain date into an archive table.